# C# 'cannot implicitly convert from double to int'

Tags: c#, .net

Cannot convert from double to int, my program is trying to subtract from it's list and add the result to a new list, but for some reason im getting that error:

```
List<double> test = new List<double>(); 
List<double> theOneList = new List<double>(); 
theOneList = wqList.Concat(rList).Concat(eList).ToList();
theOneList.Add(0);

theOneList.OrderByDescending(z => z).ToList();
for (double i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    test.Add(theOneList[i + 2.0] - theOneList[i + 3.0]);
    Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
}
```

Summary: when i print out the list im getting int's and not double's, i have lost precision on this list because of the 'int' declaration

Comment: You can't use a double value as a list's or array's index. Is there a reason why you aren't using an integer?

Comment: oh jeez, maybe because i want the values kept as double? by using (int) im getting my answers as whole numbers and thus, lost precision

Comment: the generic type of your list and the way you index is not related at all. you can have a list of strings or list of double etc. but you always need to index it using an int....it wouldn't make sense to index the 1.5th element of the list : )

Answer (score 5):

List indexer should be of type `int`, but you're declaring it as `double` in your loop:

```
for (double i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Change `i` type to `int` and use not `i + 2.0` but `i + 2` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You cant index an array with double numbers. You need to use ints to do that:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        test.Add(theOneList[i + 2] - theOneList[i + 3]);
        Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on this [MSDN page: Using Indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx)

In general, the declaration of an indexer looks like this:

```
public int this[int index]    // Indexer declaration
{
  // get and set accessors
}
```

As you can see, the indexer is declared as an integer value. So there are 2 proper ways to make your code working:

1. Changing the data type of `double` variable called `i` to `int`. This    would be best practise, as far as I'm allowed to give an estimate.
2. You cast `i`'s value to `int` before you use it as an index, but I don't recommend that.

   ```
   test.Add(theOneList[(int)i + 2] - theOneList[(int)i + 3]);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

there are multiple errors in the logic;

```
    List<double> test = new List<double>(); 
    List<double> theOneList = wqList.Concat(rList).Concat(eList).ToList();
    theOneList.Add(0);

    theOneList = theOneList.OrderByDescending(z => z).ToList(); // you need to set the list after ordering; or the old list will not change
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // change variables to integer, do you know that at least 8 values exists in theOneList?
    {
        test.Add(theOneList[i + 2] - theOneList[i + 3]);
        Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
    }
```